# dc.js: How can I calculate averages from reduced sub-bins?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have information from a cluster of virtual machines that I am trying to plot by day on a dc.js composite line chart.

Here is the JSON format:

```
[{
Date: "Feb 15 14:25:53 2017",
Institution: "institution x",
Memory: 57777556,
Nodes: 1,
Processors: 4,
Queue: "workq",
TotalCpus: 81600,
TotalMemory: 64172851200,
TotalNodes: 300
},
{
Date: "Feb 15 14:26:09 2017",
Institution: "institution y",
Memory: 57542224,
Nodes: 1,
Processors: 4,
Queue: "workq",
TotalCpus: 81600,
TotalMemory: 64172851200,
TotalNodes: 300
}]
```

I am able to plot total memory consumed over time per institution by reducing with reduceSum().  Here is my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/catkinso/cxr1L6fq/

However, I have not been able to figure out how to calculate average memory consumed per day per institution.

I know that I need to implement a custom reduction, one that uses sub-bins like this:

```
var usedMemoryGroup = dateDimension.group().reduce(
function (p, v) 
{ 
    // add
    if (v.Queue === queue)
    {
        p[v.Institution] = (p[v.Institution] || 0) + (v.Memory / v.TotalMemory);
    }
    return p;
},
function (p, v) 
{ 
    // remove
    if (v.Queue === queue)
    {
        p[v.Institution] -= (v.Memory / v.TotalMemory);
    }
    return p;
},
function () 
{ 
// init
    return {};
});
```

But I am unsure how to create a custom reduction that creates sub-bins while also calculating an average per day.  Ultimately I hope to plot that reduction across a composite time chart with lines for each institution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend not calculating averages in groups. Calculate the numerator and denominator. Then calculate the average when you are going to display the data. I think your problem is more that you are calling `reduceSum` on the same group over and over. You're just replacing the reducer of the group each time. You need to create a group per institution and then use this technique to combine them: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#combine-groups (You could also track each average on a separate property of one group. Either way works.)

Comment: Thanks Ethan!  Your comment helped guide me in a better direction!  Here is an updated Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/catkinso/475nysw8/5/

Comment: [Thanks again!](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/001/274/brofistcover.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is what I did...

Create a dimension for institution names:

```
institutionDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                                    if (d.Queue === queue) {
                                        return d.Institution;
                                    }
                                })
```

Then create an array of all institution names:

```
 var institutions = [];
 var names = institutionDimension.group().all();

 names.forEach(function (x) {
      if (institutions.indexOf(x.key) === -1) {
           institutions.push(x.key);
       }
 });

 institutions.sort();
```

Then for each institution create a group:

```
var institutionGroups = [];
institutions.forEach(function (institution) 
{
     institutionGroups.push(createAverageMemoryGroup(dateDimension,queue,institution));
});

function createAverageMemoryGroup(dimension, queue, institution)
{
    var group = dimension.group()
        .reduce(
            function (p, v) {
                if (v.Queue === queue && v.Institution === institution) {
                    ++p.count;
                    p.queue = queue;
                    p.aggregateMemory += v.Memory/1000000;
                    p.averageMemoryUsed = p.count ? d3.round((p.aggregateMemory / p.count), 2) : 0;
                }
                return p;
            },
            function (p, v) {
                if (v.Queue === queue && v.Institution === institution) {
                    --p.count;
                    p.aggregateMemory -= v.Memory/1000000;
                    p.averageMemoryUsed = p.count ? d3.round((p.aggregateMemory / p.count), 2) : 0;
                }
                return p;
            },
            function () {
                return {
                    count: 0,
                    aggregateMemory: 0,
                    averageMemoryUsed: 0,
                    queue
                };
            });

    return group;
}
```

Then for each group, create a composition:

```
var composition = createComposition(usedMemoryTimeChart, dateDimension, institutionGroups, institutions);    
function createComposition(chart, dimension, groups, institutions)
    {
        var composition = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < institutions.length; i++) {
            composition.push(
                dc.lineChart(chart)
                .dimension(dimension)
                .colors(getColor(i))
                .group(groups[i], institutions[i])
                .dashStyle([2, 2])
                .valueAccessor(function (x) {
                    return x.value.averageMemoryUsed;
                })
                );
        }

        return composition;
    }
```

And lastly, apply the composition to the chart:

```
usedMemoryTimeChart.compose(composition);
```

[image]